# Xamarin Forms unhandledexception logging

Tags: c#, logging, xamarin, error-handling, xamarin.forms

I would like to capture all unhandled exception in my Xamarin PCL (portable class library), but cant figure out how to hook up the **UnhandledException** method?

I can see I can do it in the windows(device) specific project; but not in the PCL?

I am basically trying to use the PCLStorage to log errors but this is blocking me.

### Update

I have also tried using a dependency service to write via a non PCL approach.
When an error is thrown it is caught by the **App.gi.cs** file which is auto generated. Its then propagate to UnhandledException method that I have hooked up the window 8.1 project.

I have tried to use the dependency service to write to a file, but due to the code being async think it is exiting before it can write the logs, as it is an unhandled exception.

```
await DependencyService.Get<IFileWriter>().ErrorAsync(e.Exception);
```

Is there a way to write to a file in a non async manner as async seems to be all over the place; making this rather difficult.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I got it working by blocking the main thread from existing until the logs had been written. This was done from Windows Project for the main **App.xaml.cs** file.

The main bits to take note of are the **ManualResetEvent** object and the calling of the **WaitOne** and **Set** methods which will block and resume the main thread.

I had to store the exception in a variable too, as it was loosing the stack trace if I used the **e.Exception** directly in the anonymous async method.

```
private static readonly ManualResetEvent resetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

public App()
{

    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.Suspending += OnSuspending;

    this.UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
    {
        var exception = e.Exception;
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            await DependencyService.Get<IFileWriter>().ErrorAsync(exception);
            resetEvent.Set();
        });

        resetEvent.WaitOne();
    };
}
```

For more completeness I have included the DependencyService Window's project code method that writes to the local storage.

```
private async Task WriteToLogFile(string message, string messageType)
{
    var storageFolder = await GetStorageFolder();
    var file = await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync(FormatDateForLogName(), CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    try
    {
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(), Encoding.UTF8))
        {
            writer.BaseStream.Seek(writer.BaseStream.Length, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            writer.Write(string.Format("{0}{1} - {2}: {3}", System.Environment.NewLine, FormatLogPrefix(), messageType, message));
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(err.Message);
    }
}

private async Task<StorageFolder> GetStorageFolder()
{
    StorageFolder local = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    return await local.CreateFolderAsync(LogFolderName, CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
}
```

Comment: this is just for windows project not xamarin forms

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += (s, e) =>
        {
            Mvx.Error("Task exception from {0}: {1}", s.GetType(), e.Exception.ToString());
            if (!e.Observed)
                e.SetObserved();
        };
```

This only works in the final app project, but will catch all exceptions triggered by your PCL libs too.

```
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += (s, e) =>
        {
            var ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;
            Mvx.Error("Domain Exception from  {0}: {1}", s.GetType(), ex != null ? ex.ToString() : e.ToString());
        };
```

Comment: Hi Softlion, 
I have tried the first bit of code and that doesnt event get hit!

I cant figure out where to put the AppDomain.CurrentDomain code as my windows 8.1 app doesn't seem to have AppDomain(cant find it)

Comment: Don't put this into your PCL, only the final app project

Comment: @Softlion can you please clarify, which code can be in PCL and which has to be in the platform project, please? In the future please avoid saying "this".

Comment: @Edgaras pcl don’t exist anymore.